# Event Verification After Attaching using "on"

Tags: jquery

I have attached an event using "on" later I want to verify that does the control contain this event.

Example:

```
//adding an event
$("#divControls").on('change',".myclass input", myfunction());

//verifying the event

if($(".myclass input"].change)
{
   // logic
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

as it is delegated event, you just need to check for parents:

```
var $inputWithBoundChange = $(".myclass input").filter(function(){return $(this).closest('"#divControls"').length})
```

This will return all input inside .myclass element which have delegated event already bound.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 $(document).on('change',"#divControls .myclass input", myfunction);
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer a little bit more.

Comment: I have multiple inputs but some inputs should contain change logic. I want to attach an event on page load just like (Jquery:bind). Later I want to validate that if input has change property then perform some action. Because I can not use (jquery:bind). Earlier same functionality was achieved by using "bind" but now we are using "on".

Answer (score 0):

You can try by iterating events bound for that element.

```
 jQuery.each($('#divControls').data('events'), function(i, event){

    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){

        console.log( handler.toString() );

    });

});
```